# Images do not load correctly unless reloadData is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionViewController with a custom UICollectionViewCell with an image and a label outlet. The images only fill correctly AFTER I press reload to reload the data. I notice that the labels disappear too, though I feel they 
are just behind the images.

What am I doing wrong?

ON LOAD

[image]

AFTER RELOADING THE DATA

This is how big the images should be when the view is loaded.

[image]

I set the cells to be a factor of how big the screen size is. NSLogging the Frames I can see that the Cell size and the image size are the same.

```
Cell size: 124.85 
PhotoView size: {{0, 0}, {124.85, 124.85}}
```

**CollectionViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HomeModel.h"
@interface CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
@end
```

**CollectionViewController.m**

```
#import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"


#define SPACE_BETWEEN_CELLS 0.05

@interface CollectionViewController () {

    NSArray * _feedItems;
}
- (IBAction)reloadUserData:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";


- (IBAction)reloadUserData:(id)sender {
     [self.collectionView reloadData];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;

    _feedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.jpg", @"2.jpg", @"3.jpg", @"4.jpg", @"5.jpg", nil];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_feedItems count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    //IMAGE
    cell.photoView.frame    = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height);
    cell.photoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:128 green:128 blue:128 alpha:0.5];

    cell.photoView.image    = [UIImage imageNamed:[_feedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSLog(@"PhotoView size: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.photoView.frame) );




    return cell;
}



#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat size = ( [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 3 ) - ( SPACE_BETWEEN_CELLS * 3);

    NSLog(@"Cell size: %f ", size);

    return CGSizeMake( size, size);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    return SPACE_BETWEEN_CELLS;
}



@end
```

Here is my custom cell

**CollectionViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@end
```

**CollectionViewCell.m**

```
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation CollectionViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {}

@end
```

Comment: `cell.photoView.frame    = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height);` - the first time the cell is created that frame size is 0,0. Use autolayout to keep the imageView sized to the cell.

Comment: If i remove that line, on reload the images do not get resized

Comment: Yes you need to use auto layout to set the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the height of the image view (Photo view),
Do not keep its height same as the height of the cell, otherwise the label will also disappear.

```html
    cell.photoView.frame    = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height - 20);
```

If using auto layout give the image view, constraints from (top, left and right and set its height), and for the label give constraints (bottom and align it horizontally center in the cell).

If using auto resizing then set the following settings,

for image view

[image]

and for the label

[image]

Comment: Part of the issue was the AutoLayout. Though the label wasn't being pushed out of view, it was hidden behind the Image. Thanks for your help. AutoLayout is a nightmare at times.